# How to add and access additional properties once logged in using Azure Active Directory in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, active-directory, asp.net-identity

I have setup an Azure Active Directory (AD) to log in an MVC Web application. Once logged in, only Email ID is returned from Azure. I need to extend this to get some basic properties using Email ID as a key field; to map AD and my database which contains additional details.

**My requirements are below**

1. Need to use AD for login.
2. Once logged in  Azure will return Email ID (which can be accessed from HttpContext.User.Identity.Name) I need to fetch some additional profile related properties from my Database during login time and store in extended identity.
3. I don't want to fetch these additional details every time from Database on each action execution, instead, I need to get those additional properties from my DB after user logged in as like MVC normal authentication.
4. AD Graph API is not useful because I don't want to store additional details in Azure instead it will be available in my Database.

Comment: Did you find the solution to add additional properties post authentication from dB to identify

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the OWIN middleware for OpenIdConnect, you can add your custom data as custom claims after the middleware has validated the token.

So something like:

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
{
  // Rest of config left out for brevity
  Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
  {
    SecurityTokenValidated = async (notification) =>
    {
      ClaimsIdentity identity = notification.AuthenticationTicket.Identity;
      //Get the user data any way you want
      //Add claims
      identity.AddClaim(new Claim("homeTown", "Somewhere"));
    }
  }
});
```

The `ClaimsIdentity` will contain the usual user information about the signed-in user. You can add any claims you want here, and they will be stored the same as the usual ones. You can then access these claims e.g. in your controllers through the `User` property, or through `ClaimsPrincipal.Current` anywhere else.

The main advantage here is that you only fetch the data once when the user signs in, you don't need to get them on each request.

Comment: I added notification as shown. But when check from controller via ClaimsPrincipal.Current i don't see those claims. I want to use .net identity with azure ad authentication at the same time.